# Is there anything that, from admin panel we can automaticaly redirect the user to different pages?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Django, python including StackOverflow.having a problem with the form submission. whenever I tried to submit the form just it refreshes not fully and it doesn't submit the form. Another problem is whenever a user submits the form he will redirect to the pending page, I wanted to hold on the user on that page until I accept an offer or reject an offer once I accepted the offer the user has to be automatically redirected to next page if rejected he has to redirect reject page.
How can I achieve this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.

User = get_user_model()


class FullStackOffer(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Python', 'Python'),
        ('Django', 'Django'),
        ('Mysql', 'MySQL'),
        ('HTML', 'HTML'),
        ('CSS', 'CSS'),
        ('Tailwindcss', 'Tailwind CSS'),
        ('Bootstrap', 'Bootstrap'),
        ('Javascript', 'JavaScript'),
        ('React-js', 'React.js'),
    )

    
    ACCEPTED = 'Accepted'
    REJECTED = 'Rejected'
    PENDING = 'Pending'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (REJECTED, 'Rejected'),
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
    )
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    development_technologies = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CHOICES)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    timeframe = models.DateField()
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    additional_comments = models.TextField()

    
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=PENDING,
    )
    
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import FullStackOffer


class FullStackOfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'status' in form.changed_data:
            new_status = form.cleaned_data['status']

            # Check the new status and redirect the user accordingly
            if new_status == FullStackOffer.ACCEPTED:
                full_message = "Your offer has been accepted."
                send_mail(
                    subject="Accepted offer",
                    message=full_message,
                    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                    recipient_list=[obj.user.email]
                )
                return redirect('accepted')
            elif new_status == FullStackOffer.REJECTED:
                full_message = "Your offer has been rejected."
                send_mail(
                    subject="Rejected offer",
                    message=full_message,
                    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                    recipient_list=[obj.user.email]
                )
                return redirect('rejected')

        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.register(FullStackOffer, FullStackOfferAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import FullStackOffer

class FullStackOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    budget =  forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '$0.00', 'prefix': '$'}))

    class Meta:
        model = FullStackOffer
        CHOICES = (
            ('Python', 'Python'),
            ('Django', 'Django'),
            ('Mysql', 'MySQL'),
            ('HTML', 'HTML'),
            ('CSS', 'CSS'),
            ('Tailwindcss', 'Tailwind CSS'),
            ('Bootstrap', 'Bootstrap'),
            ('Javascript', 'JavaScript'),
            ('React-js', 'React.js'),
        )
        
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'development_technologies','files', 'timeframe', 'budget', 'additional_comments']
        widgets = {
            'development_technologies': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'timeframe': forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
    


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['development_technologies'].choices = self.Meta.CHOICES
        
        self.fields['title'].label = 'Project Name'
        self.fields['description'].label = 'Website Requirements'
        self.fields['development_technologies'].label = 'Preferred Development Technologies'
        self.fields['files'].label = 'Attach Files'
        self.fields['timeframe'].label = 'What is your desired deadline for completion of the project?'
        self.fields['budget'].label = 'Estimated Budget?'
        self.fields['additional_comments'].label = 'Additional Comments'

        
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
        self.fields['development_technologies'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'checkbox_classes'})
        self.fields['files'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
        self.fields['timeframe'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
        self.fields['budget'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
        self.fields['additional_comments'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input_classes'})
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import FullStackOfferForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class PendingView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pending.html'
    

class RejectedView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'rejected.html'
   

class FullStackOfferView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = FullStackOfferForm
    template_name = 'full_stack_offer.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('offers:pending')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import FullStackOfferView, PendingView, RejectedView

app_name = 'offers'

urlpatterns = [
    path('full-stack-offer/', FullStackOfferView.as_view(), name='full-stack-offer'),
    path('pending/', PendingView.as_view(), name='pending'),
    path('rejected/', RejectedView.as_view(), name='rejected'),
]
```

I tried to achieve this have look at models.py and admin.py.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in models.py

```
CHOICES = (
    ('Python', 'Python'),
    ('Django', 'Django'),
    ('Mysql', 'MySQL'),
    ('HTML', 'HTML'),
    ('CSS', 'CSS'),
    ('Tailwindcss', 'Tailwind CSS'),
    ('Bootstrap', 'Bootstrap'),
    ('Javascript', 'JavaScript'),
    ('React-js', 'React.js'),
)

 development_technologies = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CHOICES)
```

visit the link and follow it
https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

```
pip install django-multiselectfield


from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


CHOICES = ((
    ('Python', 'Python'),
    ('Django', 'Django'),
    ('Mysql', 'MySQL'),
    ('HTML', 'HTML'),
    ('CSS', 'CSS'),
    ('Tailwindcss', 'Tailwind CSS'),
    ('Bootstrap', 'Bootstrap'),
    ('Javascript', 'JavaScript'),
    ('React-js', 'React.js'),
))

development_technologies = MultiSelectField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=100)
```

don't forget to include `max_length` if not included it will raise this error

self.validators[0] = MaxValueMultiFieldValidator(self.max_length)   IndexError: list assignment index out of range

some fields are changed for solving that problem in new models.py have look

```
from django.db import models
```

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, DecimalValidator
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class FullStackOffer(models.Model):

```
CHOICES = ((
    ('Python', 'Python'),
    ('Django', 'Django'),
    ('Mysql', 'MySQL'),
    ('HTML', 'HTML'),
    ('CSS', 'CSS'),
    ('Tailwindcss', 'Tailwind CSS'),
    ('Bootstrap', 'Bootstrap'),
    ('Javascript', 'JavaScript'),
    ('React-js', 'React.js'),
))

ACCEPTED = 'Accepted'
REJECTED = 'Rejected'
PENDING = 'Pending'

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
    (REJECTED, 'Rejected'),
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
)

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
description = models.TextField()
attached_files = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank=True)
development_technologies = MultiSelectField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=100)
date = models.DateField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999.99), DecimalValidator(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)])
comments = models.TextField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Sorry! if anything gone wrong I am new to StackOverflow and ..django